# Passing a callable to the DataFrame.where() function without Tilde(~) leads to ValueError + TypeError

Tags: python, pandas

In a book I have found a code which marks duplicates in a DataFrame.

The following code is used and delivers the desired result:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(frame)

dupl_val=df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated,axis=1)
df=df.where(~dupl_val,"XXX")
print(df)

id           Size             Name         Total            Date  \
0            121349100         NaN         NaN              NaN   
1            121350610         NaN         NaN              NaN   
2            124426041         NaN         NaN              NaN   
3            124436734         NaN         NaN              NaN   
4            124451775           1         NaN              XXX
```

Now if I use the same code but omit the Tilde(~) this comes to a ValueError as well as a TypeError:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>   TypeError

Sure this is because I have omitted ~, but WHY? What is this Tilde standing for and whats the purpose of this? Thanks for any responds.

If I input "000" instead of "XXX" and also omit the tilde, the result is as follows (which is also confusing and not the desired result)

```
df=pd.DataFrame(frame)

dupl_val=df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated,axis=1)
df=df.where(dupl_val,000)
print(df)



id           Size        Name            Total     Date  \
0   0          0.0          0.0               0.0 1970-01-01    
1   0          0.0          0.0               0.0 1970-01-01    
2   0          0.0          0.0               0.0 1970-01-01   
3   0          0.0          0.0               0.0 1970-01-01   
4   0          0.0          0.0               1.0 1970-01-01    
5   0          0.0          1.0               1.0 1970-01-01
```

Comment: It should work.. are you positive the tilde is the only change?

Comment: Have edited my question